# Magento 2 : CAPTCHA image display too much dots

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, captcha

I'm new in magento. I am working in custom module.

I apply captcha in registration page and login page. But, there are too much dots and lines display in image. Sometimes, I can't read text properly.

I checked in admin configuration. But, I didn't found any configuration to decrease dots and lines from CAPTCHA.

How to do manage this?

please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to :

> /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Captcha/Image.php

Open this file and go to line no 121 and 129.

Find this below line :

```
protected $_dotNoiseLevel = 100; // For dots
protected $_lineNoiseLevel = 5; // For lines
```

And replace it :

```
protected $_dotNoiseLevel = 50;
protected $_lineNoiseLevel = 3;
```

Save it and clean cache.

Answer (score 2):

Tested in Magento 2.2
The DotNoiseLevel and LineNoiseLevel are set in `vendor\zendframework\zend-captcha\src\Image.php`
You can override `Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel` and set DotNoiseLevel and LineNoiseLevel as `class DefaultModel extends \Zend\Captcha\Image`

Your Custom module di.xml will be

```
<preference for="Magento\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel" type="Custom\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel"/>
```

and model class will be
Custom\Captcha\Model\DefaultModel.php

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session,
    \Magento\Captcha\Helper\Data $captchaData,
    \Magento\Captcha\Model\ResourceModel\LogFactory $resLogFactory,
    $formId
) {
    parent::__construct($session,$captchaData,$resLogFactory,$formId);
    $this->setDotNoiseLevel(2);
    $this->setLineNoiseLevel(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Captcha/Image.php (nothing will happen after change so go below path)

/vendor/zendframework/zend-captcha/src/Image.php

Open this file and go to line no 106 and 114.

Find this below line :

protected $_dotNoiseLevel = 100; // For dots
protected $_lineNoiseLevel = 5; // For lines
And replace it :

protected $_dotNoiseLevel = 0;
protected $_lineNoiseLevel = 0;

Answer (score 1):

Starting from [Magento 2.3.5 the Zendframework has been replaced by Laminas](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Migration-of-Zend-Framework-to-the-Laminas-Project/ba-p/443251) (being the next evolution step of the Zendframework). So you have to make the changes mentioned in [the answer of Rohan Hapani](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/237146/98367) in the file `vendor/laminas/laminas-captcha/src/Image.php` (best by adding a patch-file to `m2-hotfixes`):

```
    /**
     * Number of noise dots on image
     * Used twice - before and after transform
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $dotNoiseLevel = 100;

    /**
     * Number of noise lines on image
     * Used twice - before and after transform
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $lineNoiseLevel = 5;
```